# easymock always returning NPE

Tags: unit-testing, testing, easymock, powermock

I am a newbie to using mocking frameworks, i am trying to add some new tests cases

I have the following class i am trying to test, i have stripped down my classes to bare minimum

```
public class LanguageMapping {

    protected Map<String, String> languageMapping;

    public Map<String, String> getLanguageMapping() {
        return languageMapping;
    }

    public void updated(Dictionary properties) throws ConfigurationException {
        languageMapping = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String mappingPath = properties.get(
                SealMappingServiceConstants.SEAL_MAPPING_PATH).toString();
    }
}
```

My Test class

```
public class LanguageMappingTest {

    Dictionary properties;
    Object object;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        properties = EasyMock.createMock(Hashtable.class);
        object = new String("/etc/language-mapping");       
    }

    @Test 
    public void testGetLanguageMapping() throws ConfigurationException{
        LanguageMapping mappingService = new LanguageMapping();

        EasyMock.expect(properties.get(Constants.SEAL_MAPPING_PATH)).andReturn(object);
        //EasyMock.expect(object.toString()).andReturn("/etc/language-mapping");

        PowerMock.replayAll();
        mappingService.updated(properties);
        //assertNotNull(mappingService.getLanguageMapping());           
    }
```

Irrespective of what I do, Easy mock is always indicating a NullPointerException at the following line in the class I am testing.

```
String mappingPath = properties.get(
                Constants.SEAL_MAPPING_PATH).toString();
```

I am kind of stuck at this point, not sure what I am missing - any help is appreciated.

Also please point me to any resources online to help me acquire better understanding.

Comment: Any ideas,i am still stuck with issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing PowerMock and EasyMock.

When you're creating mock instances of objects and setting expectations and verifying they have occurred, then EasyMock can be used by itself.

PowerMock need only be used if the classes/methods you want to mock are final, private or static. In these cases, PowerMock provides extra functionality that EasyMock does not.

So looking at your test class, I see you have created your mock using EasyMock, then set your expectations using EasyMock, but then tried to replay the mock using PowerMock. This won't work.

What ends up happening is that your mock object is still in "record mode" and so returns default values to any method calls made upon it. In the case of a method returning an object, the default value is null, hence your NPE.

I've changed you test method to use the `EasyMock.replay()` method and it's working fine for me:

```
@Test
public void testGetLanguageMapping() throws ConfigurationException {
    final LanguageMapping mappingService = new LanguageMapping();

    EasyMock.expect(this.properties.get(SealMappingServiceConstants.SEAL_MAPPING_PATH)).andReturn(this.object);
    EasyMock.replay(this.properties);

    mappingService.updated(this.properties);

    EasyMock.verify(this.properties);
}
```

Just an extra note, remember to verify your mocks to ensure the expected behaviour has occurred.

Of course, you'll have seen this before, but [here is the EasyMock website.](http://easymock.org/index.html) It has a lot of documentation and examples about how to use EasyMock.

For completeness, [here also is the PowerMock website.](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/) Although, while learning, I think I would avoid PowerMock for the time being.